# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError TestApplicationResponse.getHeaders()Lio/ktor/response/ResponseHeaders

Tags: ktor, kotest

I'm getting the following error when calling `response.shouldHaveHeader` . The full message is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationResponse.getHeaders()Lio/ktor/response/ResponseHeaders; at io.kotest.assertions.ktor.TestAppMatchersKt$haveHeader$1.test(testAppMatchers.kt:100) at io.kotest.assertions.ktor.TestAppMatchersKt$haveHeader$1.test(testAppMatchers.kt:97) at io.kotest.matchers.ShouldKt.invokeMatcher(should.kt:43) at io.kotest.matchers.ShouldKt.should(should.kt:38) at io.kotest.assertions.ktor.TestAppMatchersKt.shouldHaveHeader(testAppMatchers.kt:95)`

I'm using io.kotest.extensions:kotest-assertions-ktor-jvm:1.0.3 and io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:2.0.3 . Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Could you please share a complete code for your test or a sample project?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I uploaded a sample test case with same issue here https://github.com/suneelgv/ktor-kotest-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `kotest-assertions-ktor` library is incompatible with Ktor `2.*.*` because it depends on [Ktor 1.6.8](https://github.com/kotest/kotest-assertions-ktor/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Libs.kt#L15) (I've migrated your sample project to Ktor 1.6.8 and checked that the test isn't crashed with a runtime error anymore).

Since this library hasn't many matchers and depends on deprecated testing API, I suggest using [testApplication](https://ktor.io/docs/testing.html) API and writing custom matchers if you need them.